# How to integrate Zoho Crm with twilio using Php

Tags: php, twilio, integration, crm, zoho

I am creating an IVR for twilio and was given a twiml app and have decided to use php.

How do the  integrate the php file with zoho crm? I am a bit stuck.

Updates: We have created a php file for this and posted it in my github

https://gist.github.com/sjvelasquez/c55a9cca94f0852b4f267668e230be07

Comment: rtm: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml, https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php

Comment: I'll try this and then I'll update on my findings.

Comment: You're lucky you're not working with asterisk! ;p good luck

Comment: yeah, that is much much harder! hmm but what do you think? is this possible?

Comment: Sure if you can get through all the licences, developer program, poor docs. Have you seen this: https://www.zoho.eu/crm/help/zoho-phonebridge/twilio.html

Comment: yeah, I have tried that before but the problem is, I was given an audio file that I chopped into smaller parts to use for the ivr  and it looks like that in the documentation it only configures welcome,menu,busy and unavailable audio messages? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Do I need to upload it in our server's web root file manager?

Comment: Hello, I'm a developer evangelist for Twilio. I'd love to help, but I'm not sure what the problem is right now. Are you still having difficulties here?

Comment: Hi, I would like to integrate the php file in my gist in zoho CRM and I'm not really sure how to do that. Yes, It is kinda difficult and confusing.